# Hide toolbar in WindowBuilder for Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, windowbuilder

Please, can you tell me how to hide the toolbar in the following screenshot?  I'm talking about the WindowBuilder GUI Designer toolbar.  I can't figure out how to hide it.

Thanks.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/xNL66.jpg]

Comment: [plugin](http://code.google.com/p/eclipse-hide-toolbar/) that I think is about this toolbar

Comment: thanks , but im talking about windowBuilder GUI desinger toolbar , and not eclipse main toolbar .

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but i think is not possible, you can collapse the Structure and Palette panes, but you cannot hide the window builder Toolbar in the WindowBuilder editor.